# this keyword inside slim framework closure

Tags: php, slim-3

recently i started to learn API in PHP, i start to learning basic stuffs related to API then i decided to learn a framework and i choose slim microframework so i was reading the Dependency Container documentation
and i saw this example

```
$app->get('/foo', function ($req, $res, $args) {
$myService = $this->get('myService');

return $res;
```

});

here this keyword refers to Container object so i want to know how it is possible to refer an object with this keyword in PHP closure?

Comment: you mean closure, I guess (not _clauser_)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after couple of hours searching i got my answer so i want to share it

```
class A{
private $privateData = 2;

public function get($func){
    $c=Closure::bind($func,$this,"A");
    $c();
}

public function getPrivateData(){
    return $this->privateData;
 }
}


$a=new A();
$a->get(function (){
    var_dump($this->getPrivateData());
});
```

https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-closure-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `$this` is the `$app` in this context. And from the earlier part of the documentation you can see that you create the container, add it to the app. So the container is there, injected.

```
$container = new \Slim\Container;
$app = new \Slim\App($container);
```

Although Slim is a microframework - it's not easy. You use Slim 3, no problem with that. If you want to understand better how the things could be structured - I recommend this [tutorial](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html) (it's for Slim 4).